# Using multiprocessing fails

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

This code works when the driving loop is a conventional "for". When I try to get a speedup using Pool, it fails. The task is to shift the rows of a matrix by variable amounts. It comes up in radio astronomy. The arrays are large (4096,2000000) collections of uint8's.

Works:

```
shiftedDataArray = np.zeros((sizeSpectrum,nSpectra), dtype= np.uint8)

dispersionDelayList = np.array([(M31delay(i, centerDM)) for i in
np.arange(sizeSpectrum) ])


@jit
def copyNumba(dispersionDelayList, byFrequencyData, shiftedDataArray,i):
   for j in np.arange(nSpectra):
       if j+dispersionDelayList[i]<nSpectra:
            shiftedDataArray[i][j] = byFrequencyData[i][j+dispersionDelayList[i]]


def shiftRow(i):
    copyNumba(dispersionDelayList, byFrequencyData, shiftedDataArray,i)
    return i


for i in range(sizeSpectrum):
   shiftRow(i)
```

fails:

```
shiftedDataArray = np.zeros((sizeSpectrum,nSpectra), dtype= np.uint8)

dispersionDelayList = np.array([(M31delay(i, centerDM)) for i in
np.arange(sizeSpectrum) ])

@jit
def copyNumba(dispersionDelayList, byFrequencyData, shiftedDataArray,i):

    for j in np.arange(nSpectra):
        if j+dispersionDelayList[i]<nSpectra:
            shiftedDataArray[i][j] = byFrequencyData[i][j+dispersionDelayList[i]]

def shiftRow(i):
    copyNumba(dispersionDelayList, byFrequencyData, shiftedDataArray,i)
    return i


pool = Pool(processes=12)

chkByFrequency = pool.map( shiftRow,  range(sizeSpectrum) )

pool.close()
```

Thanks for considering this.

Comment: How does it fail? Is this Windows or a unix-like system?

Comment: You are updating the array in the child, not the parent. Is that the problem?

Comment: The platform is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6. The processor is an i7, with 6 cores, effectively 12. The failure is nothing is written to the shiftedDataArray.

Comment: Please explain child and parent.

Comment: With `multiprocessing.Pool` a process (parent) creates subprocesses (children) to run the worker. In linux, a child process gets a copy-on-write view of the creating process's memory. Any writes go into a private area and are not seen by the parent. When you update the array in the child, it is fully independent of the array in the parent. You can pass the modified array back the the parent in the return statement but you may find that less efficient than your original code.

Comment: Sometimes a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` works for numpy arrays because its done in parallel in 1 process. numpy releases the GIL so stuff can go on in parallel. But multiple threads shouldn't update the same array at the same time.

Comment: that is it. Thanks.

Comment: I moved the comment to an answer

Answer (score 0):

The `multiprocessing` module creates subprocesses to do work. Child processes are separate from their parent and changes made in the child are not seen by the parent. The module gives you several options for getting data back to the parent (e.g., a `Pool.map` return value, or data proxied via a `Manager`), but the local local and global variables of the child are otherwise lost.

In your case, the subprocesses modified their version of `shiftedDataArray`, not the parent process's version. Since all of these workers are trying to update the same object, its unlikely that there is a good multiprocessing (or even multi-threaded) solution for this problem.